# How to fix a problemn with DI in .NET Core

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Notificador
    services.AddScoped<Business.Interfaces.INotificador, Business.Notificacoes.Notificador>();
    services.AddScoped<Business.Interfaces.IRepositorioService, Business.Services.RepositorioService>();

    //MQTT
    services.AddTransient<MqttService>();
    services.AddHostedMqttServerWithServices(options =>
    {
        var s = options.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MqttService>();
        s.ConfigureMqttServerOptions(options);
    });
    services.AddMqttConnectionHandler();
    services.AddMqttWebSocketServerAdapter();
}
```

But the following error occurs:

`Cannot resolve 'Automa.Mqtt.Service.MqttService' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Automa.Business.Interfaces.IRepositorioService`

Can anyone help me?

Here the `ctro` of class MqttService.cs

```
 private readonly Business.Interfaces.IRepositorioService _ServiceWrapper;

 public MqttService(Business.Interfaces.IRepositorioService serviceWrapper)
 {
    _ServiceWrapper = serviceWrapper;
 }
```

Here the `ctro` of class RepositorioService.cs

```
 public RepositorioService(Context repositoryContext, Interfaces.INotificador notificador)
 {
    _repoContext = repositoryContext;
     _notificador = notificador;
 }
```

Comment: Does the error occur on the line `var s = options...`?

Comment: @aage exact the line

Comment: As the error states, you have a service with different lifetime than its dependency which will cause problems. Add the `IRepositorioService` as transient lifetime.

Comment: With transient in ```IRepositorioService``` the errors now is:
Cannot consume scoped service 'Automa.Repositorio.Context' from singleton 'Automa.Mqtt.Service.MqttService'. 

I can talk to you by email or otherwise? I will be immensely grateful

Comment: Could you try to use a `factory` when adding the `MqttService` and providing it with everything you do in the `s.ConfigureMqttServerOptions(options);`? So something like `services.AddTransient<MqttService>(() => new MqttService( /* dependencies go here */);` and leave out the lines that currently break?

Comment: @RenerLemes Can you post the code of the `ctor` of `MqttService`? (you shouldn't post your email...you'll get spam)

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know. I edit the code and put the MqttService.cs

Comment: Register MqttService as scoped or IRepositorioService as transient

Comment: MqttService as scoped
`Cannot resolve scoped service 'Automa.Mqtt.Service.MqttService' from root provider.'`
IRepositorioService  as transient
`'Cannot consume scoped service 'Automa.Repositorio.Context' from singleton 'Automa.Mqtt.Service.MqttService'`